# how can we reposition the popup and blur the main screen while using ng2-opd-popup?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, popup

1. I am using the angular ng2-opd-popup component for displaying a pop up on a click event, however I cannot find any way to reposition this popup to appear always on the middle of the screen. Is there any way to achieve the same?

   2. I want to blur the main screen when the ng2-opd-popup is opened (this.popup3.show) for which there are no options available in the default option list provided by the component. How can this be achieved?

Comment: 1. The position is normally done in the css. If you can identify their dialog tag class. Then you can override their properties, ex. `height: 50%` etc. 2. blur needs to be done in the parent, ex. `<body class="dialogOpen">`, the library or your code needs to inject a class to body and then blur it with `css`.

Comment: It creates a dynamic CSS.
The properties cannot be changed.